# Nodejs Listening to response stream on data event from http.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am studying Node.js. For this I am using useful nodeschool.io workshops. I am reading the learnyounode workshop now.

In the http client and http collect parts I have a problem. Despite I have read them and the api docs on node.js. Challenge in the first one was; "Write the String contents of each "data" event from the response to a new line on the console (stdout).". It says in the https collect part that "Collect all data from the server (not just the first "data" event)..." And refer the first one as it does not collects all data. Isn't a

```
var allData = "";
response.setEncoding('utf8');
response.on('data', function(data){
    allData = concat(allData, data);
}
```

capable of collecting all data from  the response.

As far as I have understood async nature so far, following first callback will be called when the async `http.get()` is completed. Or I am wrong the `http.get()` is not async.

```
var http = require('http');
var urlString = process.argv[2];
http.get(urlString, function callback (response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', console.log);
    response.on('error', console.error);
})
```

What happens while this code is executing. Does callback waits to `http.get()` to finish and supply a `response`, so `http.get()` is async? If so when the events are fired that `response.on(..)` lines are listening for, after its creation.

Isn't that listening a continuous process that is performed while `response` is being created, in that case `callback` should not wait for the `http.get()` to complete execution so that event listener be available for events fired by `response` object?

An explanation can be that; what http.get() does to create a response object to server write on it and finish. So it finished its job by creating response object and from now on possibly server will start to write to this response stream, and callback has already taken on, on to listening the response stream for 'data' events fired when server writes any bit of data to it. That would be logically possible.

Comment: The scope of `allData` should not be local to the callback.

Comment: updated accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a common feature of node.js called streaming.

`Http.get` DOES finish execution (by creating the stream) before the callback is called.  It is the stream that is still being processed in the callback. The end result of `http.get` is the stream object that is still updating until the complete response is received.

The way to think about callbacks is not as a function that executes when the parent is done executing, but as a function that is an argument of another function.  Theoretically, there is nothing to stop the parent from executing the callback at any time in its execution cycle.  The convention in node.js just happens to be that callbacks get executed after the parent is done.

You are correct that function callback is passed as a parameter into function `http.get` and so it can have access to the response object created during the execution of `http.get`.  However, what is also happening is that the response is a stream, meaning that it is continually updated until it is complete.

Here is the order of operation

1. `http.get` calls the external resource.
2. `http.get` creates the response object as a stream and updates it as the data comes in from the external resource
3. Upon each update of the response object, it emits a "data" event.
4. function callback contains a listener (response.on) that is activated whenever the "data" event is thrown.

Here's an example of a function creating a stream and passing it into a callback

```
function myAsyncFunction(callback){
    var result = createStream();  // perform processing to create a streaming object

    // at this point, the parent function is done so lets execute the callback

    callback(result);
}

function processStream(example){
    example.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log('chunk received' + chunk);
    });

    example.on('end', function(){
        console.log('streaming is complete');
    });
}

myAsyncFunction(processStream);
```

Comment: So, you mean that function callback does not wait for http.get to finish as I have seen in some other async functions like fs.readdir, in that case the callback only called after the fs.readdir finished reading. What is the difference and when to know this is the case?

Comment: In this case, http.get does finish executing before callback is called.  However, the end result of http.get is the stream object that is still updating until the complete response is received.

Comment: Btw, the way to think about callbacks is not as a function that executes when the parent is done executing, but as a function that is an argument of another function.  Theoretically, there is nothing to stop the parent from executing the callback at any time in its execution cycle.  The convention in node.js just happens to be that callbacks get executed after the parent is done.

Comment: I see. One that define an async function with a function as argument can put the callback parameter to be called not at the end of the definition of the parent but anywhere above the end.

Comment: In this case http.get does not seem to finish execution before callback is called. Callback has a listener to response object being created by parent function. It should be listening immediately as the response object is created. Because it will continually being updated with data.

Comment: Not exactly.  Http.get DOES finish execution (by creating the the stream) before the callback is called.  It is the stream that is still being processed in the callback.

Comment: And server is free to write to that once created stream object, response, even if the http.get has finished and now another function is just listening to that object, just that. Right?

Comment: then my bottom line to my question was correct also, which was not clear for me from the examples, but it was just logical.

Comment: I just edited my response to show you what is happening inside a function like http.get.  I hope this clarifies what exactly is going on for you.

Comment: Thanks. your comments have made it clear before. example is wellcome also. the upvoted comments of yours should be added to the answer to make the point clear. otherwise it is no clear then the docs I have searched for. You can edit or I can do it.